# Почему работает одновременно и блок if и его else?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой блок кода

```
let testObj = {
  success:console.log("true"),
  error:console.log("error")
}
const val = true;
if(val){
  testObj.success()
} else {
  testObj.error()
}
```

Проверяю в консоли codepen вроде без ошибок.

Почему в таком подходе работает и `success` и `error`? То есть первым пишет `"true"`, а потом `"error"`

Самое главное чего я не понимаю - у меня же фактически значение if-а true почему он переходит в else? Это же не логично.

Comment: У вас функции вызываются сами по себе, удалите условие, в консоли все равно будет выводиться текст.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте разберем логику вашего кода.

```
let testObj = {  // Инициализация объекта
  success:console.log("true"), // задаете свойство "Успех", который будет равен результату выполнения функции console.log("true")
  error:console.log("error") // аналогично предыдущему только значение "error"
}
```

При инициализации объекта отработали обе функции чтобы в ваш объект записать значение(отсюда вы видите в консоли оба значения "true" и "error", НО! функция `console.log()` НЕ ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ никакого результата (отсутствует `return`).

Итог: вы имеете объект `testObj`, у которого оба свойства `success` и `error` буду равны `undefined`.

```
const val = true; 
if(val){
  testObj.success() // заходит сюда потому что значение val = true и ожидаем что в свойстве success 
будет функция, которую пытаемся вызвать. Но там undefined. Отсюда ошибка 
} else {
  testObj.error()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем так. В *оба* блока не заходит. Выполните код и увидите, что выводит 2 сообщения в консоль (2 и 3 строчки) и ошибку

> "testObj.success is not a function".

Т.е. заходит только в 1 блок и в нем падает с ошибкой.

---

Проверяйте код в консоли Хрома. Или в своем вопросе даже, преобразуйте фрагмент кода в сниппет и все увидите:

```js
let testObj = {
  success:console.log("true"),
  error:console.log("error")
}
const val = true;
if(val){
  testObj.success()
} else {
  testObj.error()
}
```

Comment: Заходит в  `if`!

Comment: @doox911 уточнил формулировку, спс за комментарий!

Answer (score 0):

У вас синтаксически код неверный. В `testObj` поля, которые вы пытаетесь вызвать в блоке, не являются функциями, а вы пытаетесь их как функции вызвать. Я вообще не понимаю, как код запустился.

```js
let testObj = {
  success:"true",
  error:"error"
}
const val = true;
if(val){
  console.log(testObj.success)
} else {
  console.log(testObj.error)
}
```

Comment: Синтаксически у него всё верно.

Comment: даже если что то не верно.Почему он заходит в оба блока вот в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, еще бы хром не ругался, что это не функции

Comment: @DaemonHK, ну так надо различать синтаксис и рантайм.

Comment: @Demon__ANT, я тебе ответил, но ты предпочёл поставить минус.

Comment: @Qwertiy так это же не ответ.там ничего не понятно.Суть моего вопроса в то что почему он заходит в оба блока

Comment: @Demon__ANT, а суть ответа, что это не так.

Answer (score 0):

По идее должно быть так:

```
let testObj = {
    success: "success",
    error: "error",
    showSuccess: function(){
        console.log(this.success);
    },
    showError: function(){
        console.log(this.error);
    }
};

const val = true;

if(val){
    testObj.showSuccess();
} else {
    testObj.showError();
}
```

Или в сокращенном виде:

```
let testObj = {
    success: "success",
    error: "error",
};

const val = true;

if(val){
    console.log(testObj.success);
} else {
    console.log(testObj.error);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Ты вообще функции не сделал:

```js
let testObj = {
  success:console.log("true"),
  error:console.log("error")
}
```

Comment: Уточните, как этот комментарий является ответом/решением вопроса?

Comment: эмм я ничего не понял.Можно более развернуто

Comment: @Kromster, самым прямым образом.